# Android ImageView Memory Management

Tags: android, memory, imageview

I have a mainactivity class, that sets a content view which has a few ImageViews on it.
On the click of one of the ImageViews a new Intent is created and a new activity started.

The problem is the app runs out of memory when loading the new content view which has an ImageView on it.
Is there a way of removing the old content view or ImageViews which are no longer being displayed from memory?

Here is my logcat:

```
01-01 11:08:19.255: D/dalvikvm(416): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 15K, 52% free 2587K/5379K, external 9858K/10106K, paused 23ms
01-01 11:08:19.265: E/dalvikvm-heap(416): 1895348-byte external allocation too large for this process.
01-01 11:08:19.295: I/dalvikvm-heap(416): Clamp target GC heap from 16.703MB to 16.000MB
01-01 11:08:19.295: E/GraphicsJNI(416): VM won't let us allocate 1895348 bytes
01-01 11:08:19.295: D/dalvikvm(416): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 52% free 2586K/5379K, external 9858K/10106K, paused 17ms
01-01 11:08:19.305: D/AndroidRuntime(416): Shutting down VM
01-01 11:08:19.305: W/dalvikvm(416): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.turbo/com.example.turbo.ByReferenceBookList}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at com.example.turbo.ByReferenceBookList.onCreate(ByReferenceBookList.java:31)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  ... 11 more
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  ... 22 more
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:349)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:498)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:473)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:118)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
01-01 11:08:19.315: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  ... 25 more
```

I am using the following code to start the new activity:

> ```
> Intent byreferencelist = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ByReferenceList.class);
>                     startActivity(byreferencelist);
>                     finish();
> ```

And then I have:

> ```
> public class ByReferenceList extends Activity {
>
>   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>        setContentView(R.layout.byreferencelist);
> ```

Which displays:
http://pastebin.com/ADuE6C4N
(Sorry couldn't post XML for some reason.)

Comment: Please show your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the two following Android official tutorials. They will teach you how to load large bitmap efficiently, and they provide working code samples that we use in our production apps

[Displays Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: Surely though, there must be a way of removing ImageViews from memory that are no longer used?

Comment: What I ended up doing as a solution was following what is on:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

I created a bitmap from the resource, then set the ImageView source as the bitmap.
Then before starting a new activity I did a .recycle() on the bitmaps to free up the resources.

Thanks very much for your help people, much appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately my reputation is too low to one up you.

Answer (score 1):

When you start your new activity use like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),yourActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: What is this? It is not related to this question..Must read it carefully what he says.!

Comment: The question is related to `out of memory` and the OP starts an activity on every click and May be the application having memory leaks and due to that older activities. Thats why i have suggested to finish the previous activity before launching a new one @PiyushGupta

Comment: I have posted my logcat.

Comment: @user1290717 have you used this code to start your activity? And plese post some code too.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the same problem but scenario was a bit different. try using `BitmapFactory.Options` class. And set the property of `InSampleSize` in power of two. If will decrease the size of image.

When you create image/bitmap, then pass the `Options` as a parameter.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.InSampleSize = 2; // It can be 2, 4 ,8 ....    
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.Create(Bitmap bm, options);
```

I am not sure about code. just read the Android docs.

Thank you!